Undefined layer in Openlayers 9.1.0
I have a rather large application where I recently upgraded from OL 7.3.0 to 9.1.0. From time to time, i get this error message in the console:
Layer.js:532 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible')
    at inView (Layer.js:532:1)
    at TileLayer.isVisible (Layer.js:326:1)
    at TileLayer.getAttributions (Layer.js:339:1)
    at eval (Attribution.js:198:1)
    at Array.flatMap (<anonymous>)
    at Attribution.collectSourceAttributions_ (Attribution.js:198:1)
    at Attribution.updateElement_ (Attribution.js:229:1)
    at Attribution.render (Attribution.js:336:1)
    at Map.dispatchEvent (Target.js:114:1)
    at Map.renderFrame_ (Map.js:1608:1)

The problem in the OL code is in the inView function where layerState is undefined.
export function inView(layerState, viewState) {
  if (!layerState.visible) {
    return false;
  }
....
}

Anyone have an idea to what could be wrong here?
I have good mix of ImageWMS, TileWMS and TileImage layers in my application.
I think I have eliminated enough other layers to say that its a ImageLayer layer that is causing the problem, but I am not sure. I have tried to look at the documentation and listen to any eventHandlers, but nothing...

This might be a bug as there was a significant change made for version 7.4.0 see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14599  You would need a small reproduceable example for it to be investigated.

Hi there ! I've got the same issue since a moment. It's non-blocking for me so I left it aside but did you found a quick fix to this ?
